# Yii check if user is logged before every page

Tags: php, yii

I have to check if user is logged before rendering every page example:

http://mypage.com/site/about

at begining check if user is logged in, if not - redirect tom login page
I don't want to add it in every single componene, how to to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use access rule to achevie this would be a better way:

```
public function accessRules()
{
     return array(
         array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'contact' actions
              'actions'=>array('index','contact'),
              'users'=>array('*'),
         ),
         array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'delete' and 'update' actions
              'actions'=>array('update','delete'),
              'users'=>array('@'),
         ),
         array('deny',  // deny all users
               'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
     );
}
```

if you really want one-place checking,,then go to `component/controller` and do it in the controller. because all controller inherits from that controller.

Comment: i dont want to place it in every single controller, i need global solution

Comment: where can I find `component/controller`?

Comment: @user2075220 then create a BaseController and have this controller extend the BaseController

Comment: @Ruben I'm not sure about that, but you should look for it in the yii framework folder

Comment: @TimoHuovinen is it yii\base\controller ?

Answer (score 8):

You can also check using this if it is true then user is not logged in else logged in

```
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
     //not logged user
    }else{
     //loggedin user
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to place it in every single controller, i need global solution

Answer (score 3):

You can write a check in the `init()` function of the controller. Which will redirect the user if he is not logged in

```
public function init()
{
    if(!isset(Yii::app()->session['user']))
    {
        $this->redirect(array('login/'));
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to place it in every single controller, i need global solution

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
public function beforeAction(CAction $action)
{
    if(!isset(Yii::app()->user->user_id) && !($action->controller->id == 'site' && $action->id == 'login'))
    {
        $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
    }

    return true;
}
```

You need to just add the above function in component/Controller.php

Comment: can you please tell where is componene/Controller.php in Yii2

Answer (score 2):

For a global solution add accessControl to your base controller (by default `protected/components/CController.php`).

```
public function filters(){
    return array('accessControl');
}

public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Then in the controller with your login action edit the `accessRules` to allow all users to access the login page

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array_merge(array(
            'allow',
            'actions'=>array('login'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),parent::accessRules()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend components/Controller with beforeAction

```
public function beforeAction(CAction $action)
{
    if(!isset(Yii::app()->session['user']) && !($action->controller->id == 'site' && $action->id == 'login'))
    {
        $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add global behavior to your config:

```
'as access' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'resend', 'forgot'],
            'allow' => true,
        ],
        // allow authenticated users
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ]
],
```

http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-concept-configurations.html#configuration-format

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for zombie posting, but I use isGuest.

```
if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
{
  $this->redirect('login/page');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write a code to check if the user is logged in or not in a different file.

Then include that php page in every file.

You will just have to write the following code.

```
include('checklogin.php');
```

In the checklogin.php page, you may write the following to check if the cookie is set.

```
isset(cookie('<name_of_cookie>'))
{
 //User in already logged in
}
else
{
 //Redirect to login page
}
```

Comment: i dont want to place it in every single controller, i need global solution

Comment: If it is php then it is the only solution. You will have to write that one line at the starting of each page where you want to check.

    <?php include('checklogin.php'); ?>